# 3 pinned ic unknown to me

Tags: transistors

I have found a 3 pinned IC with part no S3008 on my Defy automatic washing machine control that needs to be replaced. Is it a Transistor? If it is, is it PNP or NPN?[image][image]

Comment: There is always the possibility that there are other defective parts on the board, (that caused that part's failure, or that failed as a result of that part's failure).  Unless your able to find a full schematic or a test procedure document you might be better off trying to buy a whole new board.  If you can find the board's P/N you might be able to find a replacement on Ebay or even Amazon.  You might start by searching with the machines model number.  It is quite surprising the odd things they sell on those sites these days.

Answer (score 1):

First see the comments above regarding repair of the board.

If you still want to try your hand at repairing it, an S3008 transistor seems to match a Motorola p/n (Hep-S3008) - Transistor, NPN, RF".  (Might there be a small "M" on the part, or the similar parts near by?)

One listed cross-reference p/n is NTE311, available from these sites:

http://www.weisd.com/test/GenericParts_WEISD_view.php?editid1=S3008%28MOT%29

https://www.newark.com/nte-electronics/nte311/transistor-npn-55v-400ma-to-39/dp/55R1314?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIuZLy25bz5QIVi56zCh2UWgVHEAMYAiAAEgJVd_D_BwE&mckv=sliPGFeTK_dc|pcrid|219904519387|plid||kword|nte311|match|p|slid||product||pgrid|35710142008|ptaid|kwd-10780469937|&s_kwcid=AL!8472!3!219904519387!p!!g!!nte311&CMP=KNC-GUSA-SKU-MDC

http://electronicsupplycorp.com/contents/en-us/d134_HEP_Replacement_Types_08.html

**Note added:** While the above references correspond to an old Motorola part use caution as your new comments seems to indicate that the part may not actually be a standard transistor.

Comment: If you try the repair also look the board over for any other possible burned parts.  Also look for possible shorted wires or other obvious problems that may have caused the part's failure.  When complete you might want to re-coat the repaired area with some type of water proof sealant (as seen from the pictures).

Comment: The transistor I enquired about is use d to drive a 240v  small motor from  seemingly 5v signal. Is there a transistor I can use as replacement?

Comment: That transistor (cross referenced above) doesn't seem to be the correct part for what you're describing it is used for.  If the parts near this burned part are identical could you take a close up picture of the markings.  (For the use you're describing a small triac part would more likely be use.)

Comment: Also, at this point if you are still insistent on making the small component repair (rather then the whole assembly) could you provide the washer's full  model number? (Likely located on a tag at the back of the machine.)

Comment: It might be that the S3008 number is a date code, not the actual p/n.  Is it possible that there is additional text on the component body?

Comment: The component designators for these parts appear to be TRCx, suggesting this would be a triac of some sort.

Comment: @Richard the Spacecat - I somewhat agree but so far I haven't been able to find any such triac with that p/n code. (Feel free to add any references if you can.)

Comment: I managed to take the component out to take new pictures .l don't have space here and will therefore post them as a new question. Please continue as your attempts to help are really appreciated.

Comment: The advice worked. Its a triac which I replaced with Sunrex TRG01D for which I failed to get a data sheet but then referred to L016E5 Triac, they have same pin arrangement.